# ionic, blank abstract ui-view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

in my ionic app, I do not need menu or tabs, just a blank ui-view that renders the home view. but it shows a blank page.

index.html

```
<body ng-app="starter">
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.controllers'])
.run( /**/ )
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('app', {
      url: '',
      abstract: true,
      template: '<ui-view/>',
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.home',{
      url:'/home',
      templateUrl:'templates/home.html',
      controller:'homeCtrl'
    })
  });
```

home.html

```
<ion-view view-title="home">
    <ion-content>
            <h1>This is the Home page</h1>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

why does the home.html not render into the abstract view?

the ionic server response:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8100/templates/home.html
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
```

the chrome dev tools, the only tag which renders in app

```
<ion-nav-view class="view-container" nav-view-transition="android"></ion-nav-view>
```

Comment: I'm not convinced you can do an empty `<ui-view/>` tag. Try using `<div ui-view="home"></div>`

Comment: it does not work, I still get an empty page

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle

Comment: Ops! a silly mistake, I did not provide  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');